# Menu system works but cannot close

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, awt

Okay, so I've got my menu system up and working from a JFrame. Everything seems to work really well, up until I click the button which starts a canvas. Now what the canvas does is intialize  a JFrame which extends Canvas so I can't use a thread. Once the frame is up and running it calls a method which has a while true {} after this I am unable to close the frame. This has never been an issue before when running the canvas application using static void main. How can I fix this issue of the new JFrame not closing?

Comment: Don't mix Swing & AWT components unless you have a very good reason.  For this, it probably needs a `JPanel` instead of the `Canvas`.  To turn probability into something more definite, provide a lot more details of the use-case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I fix this issue of the new JFrame not closing?

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of creating an infinite loop, implement a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Make this a rule of thumb when working with GUI application, that **Always keep the UI work on the UI thread and Non-UI work on the Non-UI thread.**

**2.** Second **doNot** mix up `SWING` AND `AWT`.

**3.** The **main() method in Java Gui is not long lived**, **after scheduling the work in the Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT)** the `main()` method **quits**. Now its solely the **responsibility of the EDT to handle the GUI.**

**4.** So never mixup the Non-UI process-intensive work, with the EDT.

Use EDT to handle the GUI.

**Eg:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){


     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                myframe.setVisible(true);

       });


 }
```